# Composition of functions in Munkres' Topology

Tags: general-topology

In Munkres' book "Topology", he writes that:

> Given functions $f:A\to B$ and $g:B \to C$, .... the composition $g \circ f  $ is defined only when the range of $f$ **equals** the domain of $g$.

But, isn't it enough that the range of $f$ is a subset of the domain of $g$?

Why does he say that the range of $f$ needs to be equal to the domain of $g$?

Comment: Subset seems fine to me.

Comment: By *range* Munkres probably means *codomain* rather than *image*.

Comment: @Bye_World Even if he means co-domain, why does the codomain need to be equal?

Comment: To make sure you don't try to plug in things *outside* of the domain of $g$.  Remember if the image of $f$ is a subset of the domain of $g$, you can just define the codomain to be equal to the domain of $g$, so it doesn't really hinder you at all.

Comment: If the codomain weren't equal, you'd have to lug around the assumption that the image of $f$ is in the domain of $g$. It's much neater by just saying the codomain is the domain of $g$.

Comment: I think it was answered with the typo fix!

Answer (score 0):

Here's one good reason why Munkres requires that when composing $g \circ f$, the range of $f$ must be equal to domain of $g$ and not just a subset.  If we allowed it otherwise, it would break the theorem that says the composition of bijections is a bijection.

Comment: Oops, I mis-stated the rule. It should be that: _When composing $g \circ f$, the **codomain** of $f$ must equal the domain of $g$_. This keeps these 3 theorems in tact: (1) The composition of injective functions is injective, (2) The composition of surjective functions is surjective, and (3) The composition of bijective functions is bijective.