# Is the inclusion function the composition of identity functions?

Tags: general-topology, functions, elementary-set-theory

Is the inclusion function $ i_{AB}:A \to B$ the same function as the composition of the two identity functions $id_A:A \to A$ and $id_B:B \to B$ ?  In other words, is the following equation true?

$$ i_{AB}=id_B \circ id_A $$

The answer seems to depend on the rules for composing functions.  If, when composing $g \circ f$, the codomain of $f$ is allowed to be a subset of the domain of $g$, then the answer is yes.  But if the codomain of $f$ is required to equal the domain of $g$, then the answer is no.  So, which is it?

This particular "rule of function composition" has been discussed before.  There was no consensus and it seemed inconsequential.
[Composition of functions in Munkres' Topology](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1289835/composition-of-functions-in-munkres-topology)
 [domain of composite function (is there a set rule)](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/638380/domain-of-composite-function-is-there-a-set-rule)

But this is a case where it actually matters.  If the answer to my question is yes, then it gives me a neat way of proving something is an inclusion function.

If the answer is no, then $id_B \circ id_A$ would be an illegal composition.  In order to compose $id_A$ and $id_B$, you'd need to stick $i_{AB}$ in between them.

$$id_B \circ i_{AB} \circ id_A$$

Comment: On the other hand, am I being needlessly formal?

Answer (score 0):

Which conditions to use to define function composition is ultimately a convention, and which to choose depends on how you intend to manipulate function composition.

In the present case, if we write $i_{AB} = i_B \circ i_A$, then the result of composing the 2 bijections $i_A$ and $i_B$ is the injection $i_{AB}$, which is not a bijection unless $A = B$. So the formula is wrong, either because we refuse to consider $id_B \circ id_A$, or because considering it breaks theorems we wish to use afterwards.

We can still write $id_{AB} \mid^A = id_A$ to restrict the range $B$ of $i_{AB}$ to the image $A$ of $id_A$. The formula $id_B \circ i_{AB} \circ id_A$ is also well-formed.

Comment: Thanks.  Yes, it's all conventions.  But it's worthy trying to get all the conventions playing well together.  So, allowing $i_{AB} = i_B \circ i_A$ breaks the rule that

Comment: Thanks.  Yes, it's conventions all the way down.  But it's worthy to get all the conventions playing well together so that, as you say, handy theorems don't break.

So excellent answer.  Allowing $i_{AB} = i_B \circ i_A$ breaks the rule that the composition of bijections should be a bijection.  That's just the kind of thing I was worried about.  This means then that we need to enforce the rule that when composing $g \circ f$ the range of $f$ must equal the domain of $g$ not just a subset.

Comment: Furthermore, we can say that the inclusion is a "prime function", that can't be factored.  Which robs me of my clever way to show something is an inclusion.

Comment: Oops, I mis-stated the rule.  It should be that: _When composing $g \circ f$, the **codomain** of $f$ must equal the domain of $g$_.  This keeps these 3 theorems in tact: (1) The composition of injective functions is injective, (2) The composition of surjective functions is surjective, and (3) The composition of bijective functions is bijective.